# Why Google places API key not works?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to use Places API for show near by location.I have added service for it and use below url.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=22.7253,75.8655&radius=500&sensor=true&types=bar&key=mykey

It returns the following error. 
{  "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this       API key.",
     "html_attributions" : [],
     "results" : [],
     "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: have you read the api carefully? You need to generate an API key...read the description complete and follow the instructions.https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/?hl=en

Comment: In mu url i'm not showing my Api key which i already have. Yes i created new project and got api key for android places api

Comment: At the end instead of mykey i'm adding api key like alzagsg566

Comment: As i wrote above i already have api key i can show it but i am getting  the error. I gave my package name and then my SHA1 and saved it. Then i received the api key.

Comment: are you testing with debug or release build ? you need to add key separately for both build types in android studio.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you try to use Web Service, not Places API for Android. In this case you cannot apply an API key with Android app restriction. Web Service requires a different API key. You can generate the new one, the only restriction that you can use with web services is by IP.

I can suggest following Places API web service documentation:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key