# Android App key restriction is not working for Google Places API Web Service

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have provided package name ( app id ) and sha1 certificate fingerprint for app, but still Android App key restriction is not working  for Google Places API Web Service

Looks like Android App key restriction not supported for Google Web API key, however before switching to plan B, I though to double check, in case anyone have found it working

**This question is not  a duplicate** of [Why Google places API key not works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938504/why-google-places-api-key-not-works)
 because in this case I am aware why Google Place API Web is not working ( because of app restriction ), but do not have a solid reason (such as ref to google doc)  for such behavior, and can't go for plan B without solid reason.

Thanks to xomena for sharing a reference to a good doc, which specifically mention, which restriction is applicable to which API exactly. Thats what I am looking for.

Comment: @xomena - you are right, that answer have answer of my question too. Only issue is no where on google doc, it is mentioned that android key restriction will not work with web api. Probably I just need to accept the fact based on answers and app behavior and not from solid google doc.

Comment: Have a look at the following document: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem. It explains which restriction is valid for each API.

Comment: @xomena - thanks a ton, that is a good enough and with a very good matrix by google to checkout in case restriction doesn't work as exception.  Please let it come as answer from your end, so I can accept it.

Comment: @geocodezip - updated reason why its not duplicate

Comment: @xomena: But now on Words How do we access Google Places API key from Android?
My all code for getting Near By Places in android application and when i try to execute code no result found because it says API Key not restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Places API web service requires an IP address restriction on the API key. The Android app restriction won't work with Google Maps web services.

You can find detailed explanation regarding different types of Google Maps APIs and corresponding valid restrictions in the following document:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem

I hope this helps!